# how to store the value retrieved from query in a php array

Tags: php

i have retrieved  a query and tried to store the id column in a array. and then i check two arrays to find the common using array_intersect func....

```
<?php

    $a=array(10);
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("data",$connection);
    $res=mysql_query("select * from usertable");
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $a[i]=$row["id"];
    $i++;
    }
    echo $a[1];
    $fb_usr_id =json_decode(  $_POST['fb_user'], true );
    $arr=array($fb_usr_id);


    $result = array_intersect($arr, $a);
    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

is the way in which i stored the retrieved value in array is correct...??
and output of this code is:

Array ( )

Comment: It is perfectly fine the way you did it.  that just means that there was no connection between the 2 arrays

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine the way you did it.

Your result just means that there was no connection between the 2 arrays.

I am not sure why you did `$arr=array($fb_usr_id);` you put an array inside of an array?

Remove that line should get you a correct result.

Right now you are comparing `array(array(...))` to `array(...)` which will never intersect

Comment: @Neal when i remove that array in this line.. i get an error in array_intersect func as the first argument is not an array??

Comment: @Neal any way to convert an array to string. actually i am getting an friends userid from facebook in $arr array and my database userid into $a array and comparing these two arrays to find common friends.. i think the array from fb is in number . any way to convert array to string??

Comment: @learn: Please answer the questions posed. They will enable us to help you.

Comment: @Neal ya $_POST['fb_user'] returns the user id from facebook and i store it in $arr....

Comment: @Tomalak, maybe you can explain better to @learn what i need?

Answer (score -1):

I would do it this way

```
<?php

    $a;
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("data",$connection);
    $res=mysql_query("select id from usertable");
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $a[]=$row["id"];    
    }
    echo $a[1];
    $fb_usr_id =json_decode(  $_POST['fb_user'], true );
    $arr=array($fb_usr_id);


    $result = array_intersect($arr, $a);
    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: While `$a[]` is indeed preferable for pushing to an array, as far as I can tell your code is functionally identical to the OP's and, as such, does not solve the problem.

Comment: Nice tomalak, $a[] and without id, and query optimized to load only id, jap same one

Comment: Ah yes, that too. But still, optimisation is not the same as solution.